# Detection of free '==' operator using std::experimental::is_detected_v : different behavior for std classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdvector, sfinae

I am trying to detect at compile time if some classes do have the 'equals to' operator defined. I don't understand the behavior of the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<typename T>
using SupportsEqualsToOp_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator==(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename T>
using SupportsEqualsToFree_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>());

template<typename T>
struct A{};

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v0{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3};

    //std::cout << v0==v1 << std::endl; // this does not compile

    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<SupportsEqualsToOp_t, std::vector<int>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<SupportsEqualsToFree_t, std::vector<int>> << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<SupportsEqualsToOp_t, A<int>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<SupportsEqualsToFree_t, A<int>> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives:

```
0
1
0
0
```

Whereas I would expect to have:

```
0
0
0
0
```

Why `std::vector` does not behave as `A` here?

Comment: Due to existance of non-member comparison function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp ? `std::cout << v0==v1 << std::endl;` has a "typo", which causes it not to compile. It should be `std::cout << (v0==v1) << std::endl;`.

Comment: Okay thanks, my typo mislead me... I just learned today after years of c++ that the std::vector has a non-member comparison function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up your operator precedence. `std::cout << v0` doesn't compile, nor would `(std::cout << v0) == v1`

Not only that, your `SupportsEqualsToFree_t` finds any `==`, not just free function `==`.

If you want specifically free function `==`, you need something like

```
template<typename T>
using SupportsEqualsToOp_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator==(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename T>
using SupportsEqualsToFree_t = decltype(operator==(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>()));

template<typename T>
using SupportsEqualsTo_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>());
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9f93e13ff8fee70)